# Can I omit "about" from "That is the boy whom I told you about"?

Tags: grammar

> A. That is the boy whom I told you about.
>
> B. That is the boy whom I told you.

I think A is correct but is B possible?

Comment: I think the best way to say this is: "That is the boy I told you about."

Comment: J.R's version is good.  "That is the boy **that** I told you about" would be fine, too.  If you insisted on *who(m)*, I'd use *who* rather than *whom*.

Comment: “That is the boy about whom I told you” would be a better way to use “whom” and “about”, but—as others have indicated—these sorts of structures are not preferred (somewhat stuffy, stilted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sentence A is okay, but sentence B is not.

The word "about" is required in this case because you can not say the sentence "I told you the boy.".  Rather, you have to say "I told you about the boy.".